# Как сделать статус печатание бота в telegram

Tags: php, telegram

Чтобы было вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно организовать такую фишку, чтобы бот будто печатает на php.
Вот код

```
<?php 
require "db.php";

$method = 'sendMessage';
$data = http_build_query([
    'parse_mode' => 'markdown',
    "text" => "Сейчас подготовлю для вас отчет...",
    'chat_id' => "chat_id"
]);


$botToken = "[my token]";
$botAPI = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;
file_get_contents($botAPI . "/$method?{$data}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение пришло от CHAT GPT))
Решение:

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendChatAction?chat_id=<chat_id>&action=typing");
file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать метод "sendChatAction".
Подробнее о нем в [официальной документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendchataction).

Используйте этот метод вместе с параметром `action=typing`.